# Javafx window doesn't pop-up

Tags: xml, javafx, fxml

I have problem when I run the main that the window of javafx doesn't open but there is no errors,I was with JDK 11 but now I switched to java 8, I think that the login fxml doesn't pop-out because there is wrong path in the xmlns.

Note: I am using jdk1.8.0_291

Login-in  xml file:

```
<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/ " xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"> fx:controller="sample.LogInController" <children>
```

main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login-in.fxml"));
            Scene scene=new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Log in");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

the output is empty.

Comment: curious: _now I switched to java 8_ why switch to an outdated version with something you had running in a recent version?

Comment: *”There are no errors”*. Well, no, because you are deliberately suppressing any error messages with your empty `catch` block. Remove the try/catch (or print the stack trace in the catch block) and report any error messages you receive.